# Populate JComboBox with Multiple Object's Data

Tags: java, swing, oop, jcombobox, netbeans-8

How to do I Populate JComboBox data from a object. What I need to do is get the data from the object to the combobox. The below is how I am querying the data from the database.

```
  /*Author Class*/

package some;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Author {

    private int authId;
    private String authName;
    private String authInitals;

    public int getAuthId() {
        return authId;
    }

    public void setAuthId(int authId) {
        this.authId = authId;
    }

    public String getAuthName() {
        return authName;
    }

    public void setAuthName(String authName) {
        this.authName = authName;
    }

    public String getAuthInitals() {
        return authInitals;
    }

    public void setAuthInitals(String authInitals) {
        this.authInitals = authInitals;
    }

        public void getAuth() {
        DBConnection db;
        Connection dbcon;

        try{
            db = new DBConnection();
            dbcon = db.connect();

            Statement s = DBConnection.connect().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT idAuthor,AuthorName FROM `lms`.`author`");

            if(rs.next()) {
                this.setAuthId(rs.getInt(1));
                this.setAuthName(rs.getString(2));
            }

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
/*end of class*/
```

This is the auto generated code from netbeans:

```
cmbxAuth1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            cmbxAuth1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    cmbxAuth1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmbxAuth1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
jPanelUpdateBooks.add(cmbxAuth1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(150, 240, 350, 30));
    cmbxAuth1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
```

From the UI I'm add the data retrieved using the query via the the class like so:

```
private void cmbxAuth1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    au.getAuth();
    cmbxAuth.addItem(au.getAuthId()+" | "+au.getAuthName());
}
```

I'm concatenating the output with an Id which is an Int and Name which is a string. Now this doesn't load all the data queried from the database to the combo box what did I do wrong ? what is the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(rs.next()) {
    this.setAuthId(rs.getInt(1));
    this.setAuthName(rs.getString(2));
}
```

You only ever have one instance of the Author object. Every time you read a row from the ResultSet you reset the id/name of the Author. You need to either:

1. Create a new Author object and add this object to a List of Authors. Then you need to iterate through this List and add each author to the combo box. Basically, the database code does NOT belong in the Author object.
2. Every time you read a row from the ResultSet you add the id/name to the combo box. This is another reason why Database logic doesn't belong in the Author class.